# Store and retrieve coordinates using python and yaml

Tags: python, coordinates, yaml

I'm trying to store some Cartesian coordinates in a YAML file, and then retrieve it using python, and generate a tuple from it. I've tried the following way

points.yml

```
type:
    - point: [0, 0]
    - point: [50, 50]
    - point: [1500, 750]
    - point: [450, 1500]
```

and i'm reading the data from yaml using this code:

```
 with open('points.yml', 'r') as f:
     doc = yaml.load(f)
 points = [tuple(d.values()) for d in doc["type"]]
```

I'm getting a list of tuples of lists

an example of the data that I'm trying to generate is:

```
points = (0,0),(50,50),(1500,750),(450,1500)
```

I can store the data in the XML format to, if it fits better in this situation.

There isn't a fixed number of points, i can have 2 or 20.

I need this tuple in order to use some draw functions from Pillow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have "tuned" your yaml file a bit:

```
type:
  points:
    - [0, 0]
    - [50, 50]
    - [1500, 750]
    - [450, 1500]
```

Code:

```
import yaml

with open('points.yml', 'r') as f:
     doc = yaml.load(f)

print([tuple(x) for x in doc['type']['points']])
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (50, 50), (1500, 750), (450, 1500)]
```

Code for the original yaml file:

```
import yaml

with open('points.yml', 'r') as f:
     doc = yaml.load(f)

print([tuple(p['point']) for p in doc['type']])
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (50, 50), (1500, 750), (450, 1500)]
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much!

didn't know it could be so simple!